# How to copy file from one path to other using django-storages and amazon S3?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, storage

```
im = storage.open('old_path_filename', 'r')
strorage.save('new_path_with_old_filename', im)
```

In my django proect I am using django-storages and amazon S3 for my static and media files. I nead to save old file with new path in amazon and old filename. Could you help me?

Comment: did you ever get this question figured out?

Answer (score 11):

this way you do not download content to save it

```
# Bucket: bucket name
# Key: file path
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage
s3 = S3Boto3Storage()

def copy(Bucket_A, Bucket_B, Key_A, Key_B):
    copy_source = {'Bucket': Bucket_A, 'Key': Key_A}
    s3.bucket.meta.client.copy(copy_source, Bucket_B, Key_B)
    s3.delete(Key_A)
    return Key_B

def move(Bucket_A, Bucket_B, Key_A, Key_B):
    copy(Bucket_A, Bucket_B, Key_A, Key_B)
    s3.delete(Key_A)
    return Key_B
```

Comment: I guess you should delete `s3.delete(Key_A)` line on copy function

Comment: And is there some robust way to achieve this independently of the storage used? Doesn't django provide such a utility function?

Answer (score 9):

You can use Django's `ContentFile` to do this

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

new_file = ContentFile(original_file.read())
new_file.name = original_file.name

example = Example()
example.file = new_file
example.save()
```

Comment: This is very computing extensive.